# $f$ differentiable on $[a,b]$, but not Lipschitz

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Question 11-37(d) of Spivak's *Calculus*, 4th ed., asks

> If $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$, is $f$ Lipschitz of order $1$ on
>   $[a,b]$?

The phrase "differentiable on $[a,b]$" is a little ambiguous: it could mean "continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$", or it could mean "differentiable on $(a,b)$, with one-sided derivatives existing at $a$ and $b$."

Evidently he means the former, since in the answer book he gives the counterexample $x\mapsto x^2 \sin \left(1/x^2\right)$ on $[0,1]$. (It seems $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$ is a simpler example.)

It made me wonder what is the answer under the latter interpretation. Is it possible that $f$ is not Lipschitz of order $1$ on $[a,b]$ if the one-sided derivatives exist at $a$ and $b$?

More broadly, is is possible that $f'$ is unbounded on $[a,b]$ if it exists everywhere on $(a,b)$ and the one-sided derivatives exist at $a,b$?

I believe the answer to the second question is yes, because if 
$$g:x\mapsto \begin{cases}\frac{\sin \left( 1/x^3 \right)}{x} & x>0 \\ 0 & x=0,\end{cases}$$
then $f: x\mapsto \int_0^x g(\xi)d\xi$ has unbounded derivative on $[-1,1]$, and I claim that it is differentiable at zero (as one can show by substitution followed by integration by parts).

I'm not sure that $f$ is not Lipschitz on $[-1,1]$, though. Can anyone tell me that it is/isn't, or does anyone have a different example of $f$ that is differentiable on $(a,b)$, with one-sided derivatives, existing at $a,b$, but not Lipschitz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spivak's counterexample (with $f(0)=0$) is already the example you seek, Eric. It *is* differentiable at $0$ and has unbounded derivative.

Comment: Quite right! Thank you very much. Further, I believe I missed that if there exist a sequence of non-empty intervals $(a_i,b_i)$ such that $f'(x)\geq i$ for $x\in (a_i,b_i)$, we can show that $f$ is not Lipschitz by employing the mean-value theorem. Do you agree?

Comment: Sure. And best of fortune to you as your saga continues at UCLA!

Comment: That means a lot to me, coming from you. Thank you!